# Let $a,b,x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$, with $ax-by=1$. How to prove that $gcd(a+b,x+y)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My guess is that if i start with this  $ax-by=1$, by transforming that into a $gcd()$ form, like $gcd(ax,-by)$, or $gcd(a,-b)$ and this way i could be able to reach the end result. However, i can't reach anywhere useful and i'm very unsure about a lot of things. I'm new in number theory. If anyone could help, i would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that:

$(a+b)x - (x+y)b = ax - by = 1$

By Bezout's identity, we get the result

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain a bit more? How did you get $(a+b)x-(x+y)b$ ? How did you start?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra Bezout's identity is very important and you should keep it in mind whenever the task is to prove that the gcd of two numbers is $1$. Here, we also have an equation relating $a,x,y,b$ and $1$, so it is highly likely that Bezout's identity might be useful. Now, the task is to find two numbers such that $m(a+b) + n(x+y)=1$, which can be fairly easily found by looking at the equation

Comment: @AhmedHussein Conceptually it can be viewed as a row operation on  determinant - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have $ax-by=1$.

If $\gcd (a+b,x+y)\geq2=k$ then you would have $a+b=ck$ and $x+y=dk$ for some integers $c$ and $d$. Then if you substitute $a=ck-b$ and $x=dk-y$ into $ax-by$ you arrive at $ax-by=(ck-b)(dk-y)-by=cdk^2-cky-dkb=k(cdk-cy-db)$ which is product of two integers where one is $k\geq2$ and so $k(cdk-cy-db)$ would not be equal to $1$ if $\gcd (a+b,x+y)\geq2=k$, so we arrived at the contradiction so we have $\gcd (a+b,x+y)=1$.

Comment: Not as elegant as Ahmed Hussein's answer, but I prefer this because it shows how the result could be gotten by a natural series of steps.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks, this is really the most elementary way that I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

It is immediate from a row operation on a determinant

$$ 1 \,=\, \begin{vmatrix} a & b\\ y & x\end{vmatrix} \,=\, \begin{vmatrix} a & a+b\\ y & y+x\end{vmatrix}$$